# How to prove this inequality $\frac{a}{\sqrt{b^2+b+1}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt{c^2+c+1}}+\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+a+1}}\ge\sqrt{3}\;?$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, holder-inequality

> Let $a,b,c\ge 0$, and assume $a+b+c=3$.
> I'd like to show that
> $$\frac{a}{\sqrt{b^2+b+1}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt{c^2+c+1}}+\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+a+1}}\ge\sqrt{3}$$

My try: Use Hölder inequality
$$\left(\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{b^2+b+1}}\right)\left(a\sqrt{b^2+b+1}\right)^2\ge (a+b+c)^3\,,$$
then we only need to prove this
$$\sum_{cyc}a(b^2+b+1)=\sum_{cyc}(ab^2+ab+a)\le 9$$
but
$$ab^2+bc^2+ca^2+ab+bc+ac\le 6$$
is not true.

So I can't prove it.

Comment: No,This can't use dearrangement inequality.and $\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+a+1}}\ge\dfrac{1}{3}$ is not true

Comment: Hello,$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ is also can't true,such $a=0.00000001$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to use two facts. The first one can be obtained as following:
$$\begin{align}
ab + bc + ca &\leqslant a^2 + b^2 + c^2, \\
3(ab + bc + ca) &\leqslant (a + b + c)^2 = 9, \\
ab + bc + ca &\leqslant 3.
\end{align}$$

And the second one:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + x + 1}} \geqslant \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} - \frac{x}{2\sqrt{3}}$$
([here's](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tangent%20line%20to%201/sqrt%28x%5E2%20%2b%20x%20%2b%201%29%20at%20x%20=%201) Wolfram Alpha visualization, a bit later I'm going to prove it more rigorously).

So, putting it all together:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{a}{\sqrt{b^2 + b + 1}} + \frac{b}{\sqrt{c^2 + c + 1}} + \frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2 + a + 1}} &\geqslant \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(a + b + c) - \frac{ab + bc + ca}{2\sqrt{3}} \\
&\geqslant \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = \sqrt{3}
\end{align}$$

---

**Lemma.** $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + x + 1}} \geqslant \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} - \frac{x}{2\sqrt{3}},\ \forall x \geqslant 0$.

Note that $\displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} - \frac{x}{2\sqrt{3}} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}(3 - x) < 0$ for $x > 3$. So, for these $x$ we get obvious inequality that square root of something is greater than $0$.

For $x \in [0, 3]$:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + x + 1}} \geqslant \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} - \frac{x}{2\sqrt{3}} &\Longleftrightarrow 12 \geqslant (x^2 + x + 1)(3 - x)^2 \\
&\Longleftrightarrow x^4 - 5x^3 + 4x^2 +3x - 3 \leqslant 0 \\
&\Longleftrightarrow (x - 1)(x^3 - 4x^2 + 3) \leqslant 0 \\
&\Longleftrightarrow (x - 1)^2(x^2 - 3x - 3) \leqslant 0
\end{align}$$
which is true because roots of $x^2 - 3x - 3$ are:
$x_1 = \frac{1}{2}(3 - \sqrt{21}) < 0$,
$x_2 = \frac{1}{2}(3 + \sqrt{21}) > 3$.
So for $x \in [0, 3]$ holds $x^2 - 3x - 3 < 0.$

Comment: nice!for last one , it is trivial :$x^2-3x-3=x(x-3)-3<0$

Comment: Geometric content of the lemma: The LHS function is (strictly) convex, and RHS is the tangent to it in $(1, \sqrt 3/3)$.

Comment: Continued comment / specification / nitpicking:  
At $\,(\sqrt 6 -2)/4\approx 0.112\,$ the LHS function has an point of inflexion.
It is strictly convex only from thereon towards $\infty$. Nevertheless, the tangent estimate is valid for all $x\geqslant 0$, as needed.